# empirical mean and variance plot in matlab with the normal distribution

Tags: matlab, mean, normal-distribution, variance

I'am new in matlab programming,I should Write a script to generate a random sequence (x1,..., XN) of size N following the normal distribution N (0, 1) and calculate the empirical mean mN and variance σN^2 
Then,I should plot them:

this is my essai:

```
function f = normal_distribution(n) 
x =randn(n); 
muem = 1./n .* (sum(x)); 
muem
%mean(muem)
vaem = 1./n .* (sum((x).^2));
vaem
hold on
plot(x,muem,'-') 
grid on 
plot(x,vaem,'*')
```

NB:those are the formules that I have used:

[image]

I have obtained,a Figure and I don't know if is it correct or not ,thanks for Help

Comment: What are you trying to plot? Your plot commands doesn't make sense to me....

Comment: I try to plot the empirical mean mean and empirical variance of the normal distribution N(0,1) (from the formul joined)

Comment: So you generate n-by-n matrix of normally distributed process and then compute mean and variance for each column. Why are you plotting it `x` versus the mean\variance?

Comment: because this is what our teacher want :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it seems what you want to do is calculate the mean and variance from a sample of size N (nor an NxN matrix) drawn from a standard normal distribution. So you may want to use randn(n, 1), instead of randn(n). Also as @ThP pointed out, it does not make sense to plot mean and variance vs. x. What you could do is to calculate means and variances for inceasing sample sizes n1, n2, ..., nm, and then plot sample size vs. mean or variance, to see them converge to 0 and 1. See the code below:

```
function [] = plotMnV(nIter) 
means = zeros(nIter, 1);
vars = zeros(nIter, 1);
for pow = 1:nIter
     n = 2^pow;
     x =randn(n, 1); 
     means(pow) = 1./n * sum(x); 
     vars(pow) = 1./n * sum(x.^2);
end

plot(1:nIter, means, 'o-');
hold on;
plot(1:nIter, vars, '*-');

end
```

For example, plotMnV(20) gave me the plot below.

[image]

Comment: You can also use `cumsum` instead of the `for` loop